# Get MSISDN number through code

Tags: ios, msisdn

Is there any way to get MSISDN(Mobile Subscriber Integrated Services Digital Network-Number) number through code.

I have navigated to other questions as well but none of them are answered.

Any help towards the path will really be appreciated.

**Note: I require MSISDN number(number uniquely identifying a subscription in a GSM) and not iPhone's UDID. Purpose is to fetch the voicemails for that MSISDN**

**Additional Information :** I just found out that MSISDN number is the combination of your **country code** and your **Phone number**.

MSISDN = CC + NPA + SN

CC - Country Code

NPA - Number Planning Area

SN - Phone Number

Comment: @adamjansch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN

Comment: Not even settings shows that number, if you need a unique identifier, try not to use something so dangerous.

Comment: It is a number related to Sim.. I am dealing with a Voice mail kinda app.. So i need the MSISDN of Sim. And does not at all is related with unique identifier

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot retrieve the users MSISDN with public methods in the iOS SDK (I'm not sure about private methods). I'd be very surprised if Apple ever sanctioned this.

You *used* to be able to get the number with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SBFormattedPhoneNumber"]
```

but I think that was removed in iOS 4.0.